# Query runs extremely slowly; is this due to a correlated subquery?

Tags: sql, sqlite, correlated-subquery

I have the following query:

```
with base as 
(select a.iid as aiid, b.iid as biid from albums a join albums b on a.iid = b.iid + 1) where a.raw like "%part 1%" and b.raw like "%part 2%" and a.raw not like "%part 2%" and b.raw not like "%part 1%")
update albums set iid = (select biid from base where aiid = iid)
```

What it does is it selects all pairs of entries from the table `albums` that satisfy a certain set of criteria, and then set the `iid` field of one of the elements of each pair to the `iid` of the other element of the pair. Seems simple enough. There are around 20k entries total in the `albums` table. However, when I tried running the query as written above, it took... some very long time - I terminated it after 10 minutes, which I found to be extremely surprising, given that something like the following query (I understand it's not doing anything productive, it's just for the sake of an example) runs instantly:

```
update albums set iid = (select iid from albums where iid = iid)
```

The query plan looks like this:

```
4   0   0   SCAN TABLE albums
14  0   0   CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 2
19  14  0   SCAN TABLE albums AS b
42  14  0   SEARCH TABLE albums AS a USING AUTOMATIC PARTIAL COVERING INDEX (iid=?)
```

For comparison, the query plan of the example query looks like this:

```
0   0   SCAN TABLE albums
0   0   SCALAR SUBQUERY 1
16  0   SCAN TABLE albums
```

So I see that both have two table scans.

The only thing I can think of that might be causing this is that the sub-query is correlated for some reason and runs on every single of those 20k rows, but I don't understand why that might be the case. Is my guess correct? Can someone explain why this is happening?

(I understand that I can rewrite the query to be join-less, I'm interested in the mechanics of what's happening)

Comment: How long does it take the CTE to run?

Comment: The subquery takes around a second when run standalone.

Comment: Doesn't it simply add 1 to (almost) all a.iids?

Comment: It's worth a try to explicitly alias, I've had that cause product joins before. with base as 
(select a.iid as aiid, b.iid as biid from albums a join albums b on a.iid = b.iid + 1)
update albums alb set alb.iid = (select bs.biid from base bs where bs.aiid = alb.iid)

Comment: @radocaw it does _right now_, but that's because I've stripped out the criteria that made only a limited set of rows from the table to be paired like this.

Comment: Can we see the actual query?

Comment: Hm, sure. Updated with the unabridged version (though just to be clear, the abridged one had the same issue)

Comment: @Error_2646 It syntax-errors, both as written and if I add an 'as' before the aliases. Not sure why.

Comment: @Dariush Ah, okay. I guess sqlLite doesn't like that alias syntax.  with base as (select a.iid as aiid, b.iid as biid from albums a join albums b on a.iid = b.iid + 1) update albums set albums.iid = (select bs.biid from base bs where bs.aiid = albums.iid)

Comment: No bueno, still the same error.

Comment: Why do you compare the 2 queries? The 1st query uses a CTE of a self join of the table and a correlated subquery and the 2nd just a scalar (not correlated) subquery.

Comment: @forpas Because from my (limited) understanding I saw no reason for my subquery to be correlated, and would like some help to understand why it _is_. The example was just to illustrate that it's most likely not the problem with some other part of the query.

Comment: What do you mean *I saw no reason for my subquery to be correlated*? You wrote that query and it is correlated because you have `where aiid = iid`. I still don't understand what is your question.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was talking about the first one, `select a.iid as aiid, b.iid as biid..`, being non-correlated. My line of thinking is as follows: the `base` CTE should theoretically be constant and non-correlated, meaning that the select subquery for its creation only runs once, right? If so, why is `(select biid from base where aiid = iid)` (selecting from the CTE) in the original query so slow, but `(select iid from albums where iid = iid)` (selecting from the real table) in the example fast as expected?

Comment: Because `select iid from albums where iid = iid` is not correlated and may be executed only once for all the updated rows (this subquery is valid in a WHERE iid = ? statement only in SQLite, in any other database it would not even run).

Comment: I can't see that this can do anything other than print a syntax error. ??